# Google Mobile Friendly fail

Tags: magento, mobile

[This website](http://www.chipguard.co.uk/) is failing mobile friendly test on Google saying content is too long etc. It seems to be ignore the viewport.

Am I missing anything completely obvious? It renders on mobile device fine.

Comment: I'd recommend editing your tags to get better answers on your question also. This is not a magento issue. This is a CSS issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your site fails two mobile-friendly tests

- Content wider than screen
- Clickable elements too close together

The first one is solvable by using the following meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

*EDIT*: But as you've mentioned, this meta tag exists in your page. Then, this means that at some viewport size, you have content triggers an unintended horizontal scroll. Try viewing your website at 841-855px wide. This is likely where the warning stems from.

The other is that your links are too small for fingers to press, which is terrible user experience for mobile device users.

From [Google PageSpeed Insights reference guide](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/SizeTapTargetsAppropriately):

> **Make important tap targets large enough to be easy to press**
>
> This applies to the tap targets your users will use the most, such as
>   buttons for frequently-used actions, search bars and other important
>   form fields, and primary navigational links. These tap targets should
>   be at least 7mm (48 CSS pixels if you have configured your viewport
>   properly), and should have additional spacing around them if they are
>   any smaller than 7mm.

Just make sure your important links have at least a font size of 14px and enough spacing around them to limit the possibility of users accidentally tapping the wrong link.

Comment: Thanks Caleb but the site clearly uses the correct viewport. And media queries are being used as they should.

Comment: Thanks Caleb, but like I say I am using a viewport and all websites that test your site on mobiles load fine. It is just Google mobile test that doesn't.

Comment: Even though your site loads fine, that is not what the Mobile Friendly test is assessing. It's seeing whether your site is adhering to a set of accepted best practices. Please re-read my answer and let me know if you need further clarification on it.